# Apache Camel - send split results to CXF endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, cxfrs

I have a route that should process request from CXF endpoint and return results as JSON:

```
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder
{

// ... Autowired:
// msgRequestProcessor - converts json {string,string} to String of "\n" delimited json string: {string}\n{string}
// RangeProcessor, SingleProcessor - create mongodb Criteria object from json string
// msgTypeMapper - adds corresponding header "msg.type"

@Override
public void configure()
{
    from("direct:list")
            .process(msgRequestProcessor)
            .split(body())
                .bean(msgTypeMapper.class)
                .choice()
                    .when(header("msg.type").isEqualTo("single"))
                        .log("Go to direct:single")
                        .to("direct:single")
                    .otherwise()
                        .log("Go to direct:range")
                        .to("direct:daterange")
            .end()
            .to("direct:aggregate");

    from("direct:range")
            .process(new RangeProcessor());

    from("direct:single")
            .process(new SingleProcessor());

    from("direct:aggregate")
            .aggregate(new MyAgg()).header("msg.collection").completionSize(2)
            .log("RETVAL: ${body}")
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson).end();
}

public static final class MyAgg implements AggregationStrategy {
    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange)
    {
        if (oldExchange == null) {
            return newExchange;
        }

        Criteria oldCriteria = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(Criteria.class);
        Criteria newCriteria = newExchange.getIn().getBody(Criteria.class);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.andOperator(oldCriteria, newCriteria);
        oldExchange.getIn().setBody(criteria.getCriteriaObject().toString());

        return oldExchange;
    }
}
```

}

Everything works fine, I see correct aggregation results and aggregation completion in the log

**but CXF endpoint always returns output of msgRequestProcessor** (before split):

```
{"string"}
{"string"}
```

while I expect to see Criteria object converted to string (that I can see in the logs).

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Where is CXF involved in your route?

Comment: @Ralf I have CXF resource that forwards request to direct:list endpoint.

Comment: By default the splitter [returns the original exchange](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html#Splitter-WhattheSplitterreturns). So it is not surprising that your CXF endpoint receives back the original request. The surprising bit is that your aggregation code has anything to aggregate at all. Are you sure it does?

Comment: @Ralf Yes, I can see correct aggregated exchange in the log.   
I'm following example in official documentation: http://camel.apache.org/composed-message-processor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first that your indentation is misleading, the `end()` is really the end of the `choice()`, and not of the `split()`; I was puzzled a while by this (as @Ralf was maybe.)

Now, the aggregation works, but its result is discarded because indeed the result of the split is the input message.

For a request/reply usage of the splitter (*in-out*), you really have to declare the aggregation strategy along with the `split()` [as explained here](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html#Splitter-Splitaggregaterequest/replysample) (same misleading indentation).

In the official documentation you mention, the situation is the other way around (*in-only*): the result of the splitter is discarded, and the result of the aggregation is routed downstream.

Comment: Thank you !   
  
Yes, you have a point there. I've added aggregation to the split(), one more end() to close the split() and it works. Have you an idea how can I implement an aggregation inside aggregation? I mean I need to aggregate the messages by different way and I don't see an option to use correlation ID here...